# Can milestones overlap?

Tags: milestones

I have project, where milestones are overlapping each other, like so:

```
 ---- Specifications Milestone ---- (Start: 01 Jan, End 20 Jan)
           ---- Implementations Milestone (Start: 10 Jan, End 30 Jan)----
```

May be different PM methodologies treat milestone concept differently, if so, is there common concept of this term?

Comment: The purpose of your question is unclear. What problem do you have that you are attempting to solve?

Comment: I'm trying understand concept of milestones and how they differ from "summary tasks"? Should they be only FS dependent from each other or other dependency types also may be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR answer, no.

Longer answer - a milestone does not have a duration.  PMBOK defines milestones as

"Milestones are similar to regular schedule activities, with the same structure and attributes, but they have zero duration because milestones represent a moment in time."

They key point of a milestone is its binary - either you have reached the key point in your project, or you haven't.  So using your example above, you'd have something like

```
-- Specifications Summary -- Start 01 Jan, End 20 Jan
  -- Specification tasks - starting and finishing between 01 and 20 Jan
  -- Milestone: Specifications complete - 20 Jan
-- Implementation Summary -- Start 10 Jan, End 30 Jan
  -- Implementation tasks - starting and finishing between 10 and 30 Jan
  -- Milestone: Implementation complete - 30 Jan
```

Its a clear way of tracking and showing that your specifications are complete, as distinct from being 99% complete, I'm almost there.

Edit - there is nothing stopping multiple milestones being on the same day.

Comment: Exactly what I was seeking for, thanks for PMBOK citation